# Python requests returning succesful POST request, but not redirecting page on Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I've got a script that is meant to at first login to Twitter. I get a `200` response if I check it, but I don't redirect to a logged in Twitter account after succeeding, instead it stays on the same page.

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/login/error?redirect_after_login=%2F'
r = requests.session()

# Need the headers below as so Twitter doesn't reject the request.
headers = {
'Host': "twitter.com",
'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.5",
'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
'Referer': "https://twitter.com/login/error?redirect_after_login=%2F",
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': "1",
'Connection': "keep-alive"
}

login_data = {"session[username_or_email]":"Username", "session[password]":"Password"}
response = r.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
```

How do I go about redirecting to my account upon successful `POST` request to the logged in state. Am I not using the correct headers or something like that? I've not done a huge amount of web stuff before, so I'm sorry if it's something really obvious.

Note: (I cannot use Twitter API to do this) & The referrer is the error page because that's where I'm logging in from - unless of course I'm wrong in doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the GET parameter `redirect_after_login` will use kind of javascript or html meta `refresh` redirection instead of HTTP redirection, so if it's the case, the `requests` python module will not handle it correctly.
So once you retrieve your authentication token from your first request, you could make again the second request to `https://twiter.com/` without to forget your specify your security token from your HTTP request fields. You can find more information about REST API of twitter here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api

But the joy of python is to have libraries for everything, so I suggest you to take a look here:
https://github.com/bear/python-twitter
It's a library to communicate with the REST API of twitter.

Comment: Forgot my last paragraph, I didn't see your note about you cannot use REST API. But why you cannot?

Comment: Twitter's authentication makes it difficult to automate more than one account - passing over numbers is a pain - so i was trying to see if i could automate a couple more myself. I'll have a look at your other bit though, thank you.